# $\lim_{n \to 0^+} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=\delta(x)?$ and $\lim_{n \to 0^-} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=?$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

Take the normal definition of step function $\theta(x)$ and delta function $\delta(x)$ such that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\theta(x)=\delta(x).
$$

I conjecture that
$$
\lim_{n \to 0^+} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=\delta(x).
$$

Can we prove or disprove this?

Then how about
$$
\lim_{n \to 0^-} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=?
$$

Comment: Assuming your first limit is sensible, your second limit is $-\delta(x)$.

Comment: Thanks - this helps - can you write an answer? do you take derivatives on both sides? or on the fraction?

Answer (score 2):

As $\eta\to 0^+$  (dont call it $n$ please)

---

$$x^{\eta}1_{x >0}\to 1_{x >0}$$ in $L^1_{loc}$ and thus the sense of distributions, therefore its distributional derivative

$$\eta x^{\eta-1} 1_{x >0} = (x^{\eta}1_{x >0})' \to (1_{x >0})' = \delta$$

in the sense of distributions.

---

$$\eta x^{-1-\eta} 1_{x >0}$$ is not $L^1_{loc}$, it is not a distribution.

We still have $$x^{-\eta}1_{x >0}\to 1_{x >0}, \qquad (x^{-\eta}1_{x >0})' \to (1_{x >0})' = \delta$$ but $(x^{-\eta}1_{x >0})'$ is not $-\eta x^{-1-\eta} 1_{x >0}$, it is $-\eta x^{-1-\eta} 1_{x >0}$ minus some kind of regularization term around $0$ making it a distribution.

Comment: Thanks voted up -- I could not understand -- so do you have $\lim_{n \to 0^+} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=\delta(x)?$ and $\lim_{n \to 0^-} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=?$

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand "distribution", "in the sense of distributions", "distributional derivative"?

Comment: No I dont understand. Can you just summarize at the end what is your answer for $\lim_{n \to 0^+} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=\delta(x)?$ and $\lim_{n \to 0^-} \frac{n \theta(x)}{x^{1-n}}=?$

Comment: The distribution stuff only means that for any $\phi$ smooth compactly supported, or Schwartz, or just $C^1$ and decaying fast enough, then $$\lim_{\eta\to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta x^{\eta-1} 1_{x >0}\phi(x)dx=\phi(0)$$ This follows from an integration by parts: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \eta x^{\eta-1} 1_{x >0}\phi(x)dx=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{\eta} 1_{x >0}\phi'(x)dx$$ The idea behind this is that $\delta$ is not a function, it is the abstract operator ("distribution") such that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\phi(x)dx=\phi(0)$$